# Programmatically importing NFT to Metamask

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, nft, erc-721

Is it possible to call browser JS to import an NFT to the user's wallet once it's been minted? I'm wondering if the following configuration can be set programmatically:

[image]

Comment: It's not currently possible, but it should be added soon. The idea is using the same `wallet_watchAsset` used for ERC20s, https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/rpc-api/#wallet_watchasset